# Images in Internet Explorer are HUGE while firefox and chrome are fine

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The images of the pictures of the trainers are gigantic while the pictures in firefox chrome or safari are normal sized. I'm assuming it is a quirk with ie with css but I'm experienced enough to know what specifically should be fixed.

UPDATE: I have fixed the images part displaying the correct size but the cell that the picture is in is still the same size as when the picture was huge. What could be causing the cell to be huge in IE but not firefox, chrome, safari.

```
        <tr>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        <td class = "trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class="trainerimg" colspan = "1"><img src = "images/deanne.jpg" alt = "Deanne" /></td>
        <td class="trainer2" colspan = "4" style= "font-size:14"><h2>Deanne Cox</h2><p>Having been in the fitness field for over 25 years, I have worn many hats.  I have owned a gym, worked in a rehabilitation clinic, taught a variety of group exercise classes, been a personal trainer, and held several management positions in a big health club.  Although the experiences were all different, the one constant was working with people who had ideas, dreams, and goals that involved self-improvement of one type or another: gain or lose weight, gain muscle/get stronger, increase flexibility, run faster, pass the fitness test to get the job, get off medication, avoid surgery, stress relief,  and the list goes on and on.  The best part is, no matter how big or small the goal, any degree of improvement is a success. And helping clients achieve this success is incredibly rewarding.  So while I am in the exercise business, it is really about the people.  And the people are why, after all these years, I still love what I do.</p>

<p>American Council on Exercise (ACE), American Institute of Fitness Educators, (AIFE), Cooper Institute, RehabTex - Exercise Specialist, PregnaCare Director, TRX Personal Training, TRX Group Training, RIPPED, CPR/AED</p></td>
        <td class = "trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        <td class = "trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class="trainerimg" colspan = "1"><img src = "images/betsy.jpg" alt = "Betsy" /></td>
        <td class="trainer" colspan = "4" style= "font-size:14"><h2>Betsy Cooper</h2><p>My passion is to empower and motivate my clients through fitness so
they can live happy and healthy lives. I also believe that the only person you should try to be better than, is the person you were yesterday! Before joining the The San Antonio Country Club Fitness Center, I was the Wellness
Director at The Towers on Park Lane. 


My previous fitness experiences include working at
the Concord Athletic Club for over 10 years.
In supervisory positions at the Concord, I instructed
a variety of group fitness classes and worked in the Health and
Fitness Center conducting an array of health screenings
and assisted in teaching the "Fit for Life" program for
weight management. I even took my
experience to the Caribbean Seas as the Activities Director on a
Cruise Ship.</p>
<p>The Physicalmind Institute for Pilates mat instruction,
Polestar Pilates for instruction on Pilates equipment, (AFAA) Aerobics and Fitness
Association of America, People with Arthritis Can Exercise (PACE), CPR/AED </p></td>
        <td class="trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        <td class="trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class="trainerimg" colspan = "1"><img src = "images/jen.png" alt = "Jen" /></td>
        <td class="trainer2" colspan = "4" style= "font-size:14"><h2>Jennifer Hartley</h2><p>I became a fitness professional out of a deeply held belief that physical activity can improve so many aspects
of one's life.  Physical fitness doesn't just make you look better, it makes you feel better, cope with stress, fight off aches and pains, and helps the rest of your day go better. I graduated from the University of Texas at Austin and I have over 8 years experience in the fitness industry.  </p>
<p>National Academy of Sports Medicine(NASM) Personal Trainer, NASM Corrective Exercise Specialty, Aerobic and Fitness Association of America(AFAA) Personal Trainer, AFAA Group Exercise, Kettlebell Concepts Level 1, TRX Personal Training, TRX Sports Medicine, Spinning Instructor, CPR/AED.</p></td>
        <td class="trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        <td class="trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class="trainerimg" colspan = "1"><img src = "images/marta.jpg" max-height = "100px" max-width = "100px" alt = "marta" /></td>
        <td class="trainer" colspan = "4" style= "font-size:14"><h2>Marta Wilson</h2><p>I have been working and playing in gyms since 1984.  I found I really enjoyed the feeling of helping somebody achieve their goals and guiding clients to a healthy and sustainable lifestyle.
  After college I worked as a Dental Assistant for many years. Even when I was working in dentistry I always had a hand in the fitness field.
  I decided that personal training was where my heart was, retired myself from dental assisting and worked at an exclusive gym in Beverly Hills.  I worked as a trainer until I got pregnant at the age of 40. I have been training in the industry for nearly 15 yrs.  
 My passion is helping women be and feel their best, I truly believe a healthy lifestyle and being fit is achievable for everyone.</p>
 <p>National Academy of Sports Medicine(NASM), CPR/AED</p></td>
        <td class="trspacer" colspan = "1"></td>
        <td class = "spacer"></td>
        </tr>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you set an appropriate doctype at the top of the page? Something like `<!DOCTYPE html>` (HTML 5) or `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` (HTML 4)

Comment: Yes and it doesnt change anything with or without it.

Comment: Looks like you're using tables for layout (using `class="spacer"`, et al.) Use tables only for tabular data.  Also, [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/check).  You'll have better results cross-browser.

Comment: I haven't quite figured out how to do layout without tables yet. On my list of things to do. And the page that is not working is validated besides maybe some changes trying to figure this part out.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed you have a max-height and max-width attribute on your last image tag. The `<img>` tag doesn't have a max-height or max-width property, but you can set it on CSS.

Try adding the following properties to your `trainerimg` class:

```
.trainerimg {
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Note that you could also force your images to have a uniform width and height by adding the `width` and `height` CSS properties to the `trainerimg` class.

** `max-height` and `max-width` don't work on IE 6 or 7, so if you're supporting that, you should go with specific `height` and `width`

Comment: Ok that fixed the pictures but the cell they are in are the same size which makes the other content squish to the right.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that the class was applied on the td. Place the height/width properties in a new css class and place that in your `<img>` tag so you won't be affecting the table cell dimensions

Comment: I meant the cell was the same size as when the picture was huge. The picture went down to the correct size but now it is in a huge cell. I tried doing what you had suggested next and that just made things worse haha.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're going to have to play around with the height and widths of your table row/cells then, to make the result better-looking. But at least your image dimensions are manageable now. :)

Comment: Haha yeah I've been having trouble with that aspect. I'm trying to make it work on multiple sized resolutions so nothing is set in stone, its all percentages. But, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put dimensions on or not... But thanks for your help on the images part haha.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the browsers `zoom`. Then find the true `width` and `height` of the images and specify the dimensions in the img tag as suggested above.

Comment: I dont remember the hotkey but usually its in one of the file menus like "View" or something. Sorry I'm on a mac. You can try CTRL+0